# Give error Alert if Value on sheet doesn't match value on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

When I enter a value on "Sheet 3" (in any Cell on the Page From B5 to OD70 & B124 to OD300) I need it to give an error (Allow the name to be entered but like color it red or something to alert them) if it doesn't match exactly a value in "Sheet 1" Column B.

I've tried some If statements with Conditional formatting but that seems to be extremely difficult for that many cells.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difficulty applying CF. Follow these steps.

1. On Sheet3, select any cell. I selected C2.
2. Call up CF > New Rule > "Use a formula to determine which cells to format
3. Enter the formula `=ISERROR(MATCH(C2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0))`, where C2 is the address of the cell you selected to apply the CF to.
4. Select the formatting you want (e.g. red fill) and click OK.
5. From the Ribbon's CF menu select *Manage Rules ...*
6. In the dialog box that opens select the rule you just set up. In the *Applies To* field you will see `=$C$2` (or the address of the cell you selected.
7. Replace this formula with `=$B$5:$OD$70,$B$124:$OD$300`
8. Press OK and the format is applied.

Cells which don't have an exact match in Sheet1!A:A will be highlighted. If you don't wnat the format applied to blank cells, use the formula below instead of the one above.

`=AND(LEN(C2),ISERROR(MATCH(C2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)))`

Comment: Ok I did that but now it has turned everything RED as nothing is in alot of the cells to start. How can I make it be normal until you enter a value into the cell and then have it read the cell and if it doesn't match then it turns red.                                                                                          It also goes clear for the whole sheet once I enter a correct matching value. But if I enter a value that doesn't match in another cell it doesn't change it.

Comment: I anticipated your first experience and added the cure to my answer. Please look at the formula at the bottom of my solution. As for the second, I can't reproduce it. Your description points to an absolute reference used in MATCH and LEN. It must be `LEN(C2),ISERROR(MATCH(C2,...`, without any dollar signs in the reference to C2.

Comment: It's now not formatting when some is wrong. It's also running super slow when I click from one cell to another. (Once I removed the CF it moved fast again).

Comment: I took a new workbook and implemented my above advice step by step. I found a syntax error in step 7. I think you must have spotted and eliminated it. However, I apologize for publishing it in the first place. I corrected the typo in my solution above. When I finished everything worked smoothly and without undue delay. I suggest you do the same. Install the solution on a blank workbook first and make it work there. Then examine the differences between the blank workbook and the one containing your project.

Comment: Note that lethargic response of the worksheet is caused by excessive calculations taking place. Of course, if Sheet1!A:A is a long column the number of cells there must be multiplied with the 95,500 cells defined by the CF to arrive at the number of calculations needed. However, there is no need for all these calculations at every click and I don't think Excel would execute more than the necessary ones. But there might be volatile formulas in some of the cells which force Excel to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a `Worksheet` event handler, since massive CF tends to clutter the sheet calculation and behaviour

Just activate Sheet3 code pane (right click on its tab name and choose "View Code") and place the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Union(Range("B5:OD70"), Range("B124:OD300"))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Value <> Sheet1.Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value Then MsgBox "Attention" _
                                                                     & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The input value:" _
                                                                     & vbCrLf & vbTab & Target.Value _
                                                                     & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "doesn't match the one in Sheet1 cell B" & Target.Row, vbCritical
End Sub
```